# Mootools - On validation fail , How to change the input boxes styles?

Tags: javascript, mootools, validation

I have put `.validation-failed` in my css file. It is like this:

```
.validation-failed  {
border: 1px solid #C00;
background-color: #FFFFC6;
}
```

This code changes the background color of the text boxes, input boxes, etc but border style is untouched. I think border is not unique with all the input items, that's why they have done it. My question is

> How to change the border color of input boxes as well
>   as to put an under line to the labels
>   associated with the input boxes?

. I have put code on

```
onShowAdvice: function(element,advice,validator){....}
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you checked if the event fired? And, what script are you using?

Comment: But for validation, your using the builtin validator?

Comment: yes, I am using mootools-more's Form.Validator.Inline

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff, Do you have any idea of this ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer. In the variable declaration section you have to do the following:

```
 // Declare validator
             var formValidator = new Form.Validator.Inline(regForm, {
                    errorPrefix: '',
                    serial: false,
                    onShowAdvice: function(element, advice) {
                        element.addClass('error');                      
                        element.getPrevious('label').addClass('error');

                    },
                    onHideAdvice: function(element, advice){
                        element.removeClass('error');
                        element.getPrevious('label').removeClass('error');                          
                    }
                 });
```

"**onShowAdvice**" You will get the element that gets validated in the variable named "**element**". In my case; the field before it is the label associated with the element. I am changing the class of that label to "error" and also the class of the element to "error".

"**onHideAdvice**" you have to remove those "**error**" classes.